# Selection sort in prolog

Tags: prolog, program-slicing

I'm new in Prolog and I'm trying to make the selection sort. Here is what I have:

```
ssort([],[]).
ssort([M|S],L):-min(M,L),remove(M,L,N),ssort(S,N).

min(M,[M]).
min(M,[H,T]):-min(N,T),min2(M,H,N).

min2(A,A,B):-less(A,B).
min2(B,A,B):-not(less(A,B)).

less(A,B):-(A<B).

append([],B,B).
append([H|A],B,[H|AB]):-append(A,B,AB).

remove(X,L,N):-append(A,[X|B],L),append(A,B,N).
```

But when I try this for example:

```
ssort(S,[5,3,1]),write(S).
```

I get `false`, no matter what I try. Can you tell me how can I actually sort the list and get the result written in `S`?

Comment: Have you traced it? Are you sorting the first or the second argument? Have you tried to test each of the predicates in isolation? For example, are you sure that your `min/2` does what you expect it do do? I am asking because you might be able to solve your problem on your own without too much effort, and because if I would try to do a selection sort in Prolog it would be a bit too different from what you have right now, and it is an unpleasant job to hunt down other people's errors ("bugs").

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to trace it. I'm sorting the second argument, and writing the result in the first. `min2` is supposed to find the minimum between 2nd and 3rd argument and write it in the first. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, though :D

Comment: Here is a suggestion: test your `min/2` and your `min2/3`. If they work as expected, you have a problem elsewhere (and there isn't that much code). If they don't work as expected, you can make a smaller, more specific question that is easier to answer. At the moment you just have a bunch of code and "please correct it" which is not a good approach to asking.

Comment: "no matter what I try" have you tried `ssort(S,[5]),write(S).`? it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As well pointed out by @Boris the main mistake was in `min/2` predicate because it needs a 3rd parameter in order to return the min element in that parameter. With a few small changes the code looks like:

```
ssort([],[]).
ssort([M1|S],[H|T]):-min(H,T,M1),remove(M1,[H|T],N),ssort(S,N).

min(M,[],M).
min(M,[H|T],M1):-min2(M,H,N),min(N,T,M1).

min2(A,B,A):-less(A,B).
min2(A,B,B):-not(less(A,B)).

less(A,B):-(A<B).

append([],B,B).
append([H|A],B,[H|AB]):-append(A,B,AB).

remove(X,L,N):-append(A,[X|B],L),append(A,B,N).
```

Example:

```
?- ssort(S,[5,3,1]).
S = [1, 3, 5] ;
false.

?- ssort(S,[5,3,1,7]).
S = [1, 3, 5, 7] ;
false.
```

---

**EDIT:**

As @Will Ness correctly pointed out the only mistake was the comma in `min(M,[H,T])` so changing to min(M,[H|T]) it works fine!!!. I thought that min/2 predicate wasn't working very well so I changed it in the answer above but finally this was not necessary.

Comment: What happens if you try `ssort(Sorted, [1,2,1])`?

Comment: @Boris, I've (already) noticed that when there are duplicate elements there are duplicate answers, for example ssort(Sorted, [1,2,1,1]) returns 6 same correct answers because there are the ways to put the three 1-elements in the beginning of the sorted list (3 ways for 1st position,2 for second and 1 for third so overall  3*2*1=6 ways)... I think this is due to min2/2 predicate but anyway it doe not give wrong answers... duplicates could be removed with cut operator...

Comment: Thank you for the answers. One last thing, why do you refer to `min` predicate as `min/2`?

Comment: Glad to help!!!, Sorry I was thinking the first min predicate which had two parameters, now it is min/3 ,(/3 means that this predicate has three parameters).

Comment: no need to change all of that. all it was, was a typo - just *one* wrong character in the code. can be hard to notice, visually, too.

Comment: @Will Ness, What was the  just one wrong character in the code?? Am I missing something??

Comment: a comma. i missed it too, at first. could swear I saw the correct character there. expectation driven perception, huh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138465/discussion-between-will-ness-and-coder).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a general way how you can at least localize the error in your program.  If your query fails, simply remove goals from your program. If the remaining fragment still fails, there must be an error in that fragment.

```
:- op(950,fy,*).
*_.

ssort(_/*[]*/,[]).
ssort(_/*[M|S]*/,L):-
   min(_/*M*/,L),
   * remove(M,L,N),
   * ssort(S,N).

min(M,[M]).
min(M,[H,T]):-
   * min(N,T),
   * min2(M,H,N).

?- ssort(S,[5,3,1]).
```

Because this fragment fails, your original program will fail as well. You need to generalize something in the remaining part.